# Find element by attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element with Attribute. Well, I can find elements with Id, tagName, Xpath and all other predefined methods in Selenium. But, I am trying to write a method that specifically returns WebElement, given Attribute name and Value as input.

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.tagName("Attribute Name"));
for(WebElement element : elements){
    if(element.getText().equals("Value of Particular Attribute")){
        return element;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Assuming XPath is not an option, is there any other better ways to do this?

Comment: Could you add an HTML example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: Why does XPath not help?

Comment: Your question seems to be about matching attribute, but your example is matching the text of the element, nothing to do with attributes.

Comment: Well, This application will sometimes be used by non developers, and if they can't trace out XPath, I need them to use any of the attributes available for particular element. I already had working versions of find by - Id, CSS, tagName, XPath and all. And let's say we need to find an Image with attribute <href> and value as <url>, and assuming there are no Id, class name etc mentioned (I am trying to figure out on worst cases), How to get element with just href and url?

Comment: I believe that "Assuming XPath is not an option" is a valid assumption. It's very frequent that the answers criticize the question **and actually don't answer it**. It's like when you try to buy a warm jacket during the summer and the sales person questions why you're doing that and tries to sell you a thin T-shirt. Usually, you feel you don't need to explain your life or your reasons and just need a warm jacket. Are you buying from this person? In short: I believe that first we have to respect the person who's asking, try to answer the question, and only then offer other options.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this task with CSS.

The formula is:

```
element[attribute='attribute-value']
```

So if you have,

```html
<a href="mysite.com"></a>
```

You can find it using:

```
By.cssSelector("a[href='mysite.com']");
```

this works using any attribute possible.

This page here gives good information on how to formulate effective css selectors, and matching their attributes: http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html

Comment: element[attribute='attribute-value'] working as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I do not understand your requirement:

> Assuming XPath is not an option ...

If this was just an *incorrect* assumption on your part, then XPath is the *perfect* option!

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//element[@attribute='value']"))
```

Of course you need to replace `element`, `attribute`, and `value` with your actual names. You can also find "any element" by using the wildcard:

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@attribute='value']"))
```

Comment: Downvoted because the question declared explicitly that "Xpath is not an option". So, the answer doesn't match the question's requirement.

Comment: @AlmirCampos nevertheless, I find the answer useful. I ask myself: does this answer help me, and will it help others on SO? For me, the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Worked for non-standard element and was exactly what I didn't know I needed:
`const arasUserMenuDD = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//aras-dropdown[@data-id='com.aras.innovator.cui_default.mwh_user_menu']"`));`

Answer (score 17):

Use CSS selectors instead:

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*[attributeName='value']"));
```

Edit: CSS selectors instead of XPath

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

`By.id` Locates elements by the ID attribute. This locator uses the CSS selector
   `*[id='$ID']`, *not* `document.getElementById`. Where id is the ID to search

so you can use the below code to search the DOM element with any given attribute as ID and value

```
By.id("element[attribute='attribute-value']");
```