# Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I got a html snippet like this:

```html
<input type="text" node-type="searchInput" autocomplete="off" value="" class="W_input" name="14235541231062">
```

The only unique identity of this element in the html is the attribute `node-type="searchInput"`, so I want to locate it by using *some method* of Python selenium sort of like this:

```
search_elem = driver.find_element_by_xxx("node-type","searchInput") # maybe?
```

I have checked the selenium (python) [document for locating elems](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)  but didn't get a clue of how to locate this elem by the `node-type` attr. Is there a explicit way to locate this elem in python selenium?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can get it *by xpath* and check the `node-type` attribute value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@node-type="searchInput"]')
```

Comment: CSS Selectors notation for attribute is: tag_name[attribute_name=attribute_value]. Simpler and faster than XPath

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'tag_name'` How do I access tag_name?

Comment: @JoãoFarias This works very nicely.

Answer (score 16):

Even though the question is old but it's still very relevant I believe.
You may be able to use simple css selector and the syntax is standard javascript similar to jquery or native browser support.

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.className[attrName="attrValue"]')`

Example:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.blueColor[shape="circle"]')`

Comment: What about tags that do not belong to class?

Comment: For tags that do not belong to a class, remove the className attribute from the search: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[shape="circle"]')`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method you could use:

```
save_items = []

for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("input"):
    # Get class
    item_class = item.get_attribute("class")

    # Get name:
    item_name = item.get_attribute("name")

    # And so on...


    # Check for a match
    if item_class == "W_input" and item_name == "14235541231062":
        # Do your operation (or add to a list)
        save_items.append(item)
```

Comment: Isn't this slow?

Comment: At scale, probably @EkremDİNÇEL