# Best way to get the price?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

[image]Hello, I have

What is best approach at getting the price and other attributes?
i usually uset find_element_by_id("") it seems like a better idea to use the data-column tag. How would I do this?

Comment: using the id is always faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the prefix string in ID is a dynamic value, id is different when enter this page each time. I don't think you can use find_element_by_id("id").

You can use the 'SKU Condition' value to find the matched row at first, then to find the price cell within row, an example xpath to do that:

//table/tbody/tr[td[contains(text(), 'MP-7D1Comp')]]/td[@data-column='price']//input

use driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath");

Comment: got the API to work, but that would have been the way to do it, In fact, I could iterate through a list and get them all that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, to get attribute of a specific tag you need to use get_attribute() function.

Like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id").get_attribute("href")
```

You can try to follow the same logic in your case, but you might not get a focus on needed element with selenium. Big and smart companies don't want you to scrape.