# Python Selenium, obtaining XPath given href

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, href

Once I obtain an `href` through the use of **Selenium in Python**.

Is there a way to find the `XPath` based on that `href` and click on that `XPath`?

**For Example:**

```
href = '/sweatshirts/vct65b9ze/yn2gxohw4'
```

How would I find the `XPath` on that page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

When the element is for instance a link, you can use the following code:

```
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/sweatshirts/vct65b9ze/yn2gxohw4"]');
```