# Need help parsing html element and execute script no worked

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, html-parsing

```
<li tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
   <a href="#gift-cards" class="leftnav-links kas-leftnav-links" data-section="gift-cards" data-ajaxurl="/wallet/my_wallet.jsp">                         
   <span class="width200 kas-gift-cards-tab">Gift Cards</span>  
   <span class="count kas-count">info</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I have such a html code which is duplicated on a page about 5 times, and only 2 of these blocks have information I need. Their classes are the same and I don't know what to do.
Plus, the execute_script in Firefox does not work for me.

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("rewards-contents")
                items = html_list.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
                for item in items:
                    text = item.text
                    print(text)
```

I tried to crank it on python, but nothing sensible came out.

I expect the script to display info from all 5 blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium)

Comment: If you want all `li` elements use `find_elements`. Replace your code with `items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all elements use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`. Your code should look like:

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("rewards-contents")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

To get text by `span` elements:

```
html_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#rewards-contents li")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Да, оказывается там у меня была ошибка но вместо info вывелось Gift Card что является не совсем тем что я ищу. Может быть можно к этой строке html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li") добавить ещё как то поиск по классу, если это возможно? И всё ещё открыт вопрос, почему в Firefox не работает стабильно execute_script?

Comment: Аттрибуты надо добавлять по необходимости, если не находит то что надо, можешь заменить на `find_elements_by_css_selector('li a[href="#gift-cards"]')`. Должен работать стабильно, что за скрипт?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("rewards-contents")
     items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
     for item in items:
      text = item.text
      print(text)

HTML CODE:
<li tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
   <a href="#gift-cards" class="leftnav-links kas-leftnav-links" data-section="gift-cards" data-ajaxurl="/wallet/my_wallet.jsp">                         
   <span class="width200 kas-gift-cards-tab">Gift Cards</span>  
   <span class="count kas-count">info</span>
   </a>
</li>
Мне нужно вывести class="count kas-count"

Comment: Error: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampps\htdocs\brute_kohls\checker.py", line 36, in <module>
    html_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li a[href="#gift-cards"]').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Code: html_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("rewards-contents")
     items = html_list.find_elements_by_css_selector('li a[href="#gift-cards"]')
     for item in items:
      text = item.text
      print(text)

Comment: Я плохо понимаю о чём вы, может покажете пример кода? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Этот код должен печатать `span` элементы для каждого `li`: ```html_list = driver.find_elements_css_selector("#rewards-contents li")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)```

Comment: Error:During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampps\htdocs\brute_kohls\checker.py", line 36, in <module>
    html_list = driver.find_elements_css_selector("#rewards-contents li") 
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_css_selector'

Comment: Yes, should be find_elements_by_css_selector

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sers for the hint with `css_selector`. I solved my problem in the following way:

```
`info = []
time.sleep(2)
htmllist = driver.find_element_by_class_name("rewards-contents")
items = htmllist.find_elements_by_css_selector(".kas-count")
for item in items:
info.append(item.text)
print(item.text)
print(info)`
```