# How can I select an element with a specific `title` using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

How can I get an item with a specific attribute using selenium and click on it? In my case one with a `title` of "Store Type". I've tried XPath and many other ways, but still can't do this.

The following is an example image depicting the problem

[image: page markup]

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: What thing is this.

Comment: Please share the code that you are using

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: _I've tried XPath and many other ways_ We need to see those attempts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You can get element by xpath:

```
//div[@title="Store Type"]
```

If I'm not mistaken in python is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@title="Store Type"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Store Type']"))).click()
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```