# Python Selenium - Scraping Trip Advisor Reviews

Tags: python

I am only a hobbyist with Python, so please bare with me. I am trying to run this script to collect Trip Advisor reviews and write to excel.

But once it opens up the website it throws this error: NoSuchElementException  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//q[@class='IRsGHoPm']"}

Any got any ideas on what is going wrong?

```
import csv #This package lets us save data to a csv file
from selenium import webdriver #The Selenium package we'll need
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time #This package lets us pause execution for a bit

path_to_file = "E:Desktop/Data/Reviews.csv"
pages_to_scrape = 3

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60982-d209422-Reviews-Hilton_Waikiki_Beach-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html"

# import the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# open the file to save the review
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# change the value inside the range to save the number of reviews we're going to grab
for i in range(0, pages_to_scrape):
# give the DOM time to load
time.sleep(5) 

# Click the "expand review" link to reveal the entire review.
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'expand-review')]").click()

# Now we'll ask Selenium to look for elements in the page and save them to a variable. First lets define a  container that will hold all the reviews on the page. In a moment we'll parse these and save them:
container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-reviewid]")

# Next we'll grab the date of the review:
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_2fxQ4TOx']")
    
# Now we'll look at the reviews in the container and parse them out

for j in range(len(container)): # A loop defined by the number of reviews

# Grab the rating
rating = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating bubble_')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
# Grab the title
title = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'review-title')]").text
#Grab the review
review = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//q[@class='IRsGHoPm']").text.replace("\n", "  ")
#Grab the data
date = " ".join(dates[j].text.split(" ")[-2:])
        
#Save that data in the csv and then continue to process the next review
csvWriter.writerow([date, rating, title, review])         
       
# When all the reviews in the container have been processed, change the page and repeat            
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]').click()

# When all pages have been processed, quit the driver
driver.quit()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqTgI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to finding "_2fxQ4TOx" class name in the page but it came up with 0 results. May be these are the auto-generated classes by browser to keep up with compression and its own CSS reference.

Instead, try to find elements by these attributes (which actually exist in the frontend), try finding it like:

```
container = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-test-target="reviews-tab"]')
reviews = container.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[data-test-target="HR_CC_CARD"]')
for review in reviews:
    # get date
    # get descriptions 
    # ...
```

you can also refer to this link:
[Is there a way to find an element by attributes in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium)