# not able to find element using id in findelement in selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I am not able to find the element using "id" in selenium as the id is randomly changing in every session of execution so the same id i am not getting in next execution.
As there is no other unique property is there to identify the element.

[code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ASGt.jpg)

Comment: so, what is the question? please take a look http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and make more clear your question.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Please post the HTML here instead of a picture. The picture will eventually be unavailable and then the question will be less useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language so I'm going to give you Java. You can do this by using the CSS class or probably a better choice (because of likely uniqueness) is `data-lynx-name`.

By CSS class

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.http-lynx-json-org-text-input"));
```

By attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-lynx-name='username']"));
```

You really should read the question that I duped this one to:
[Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)

Also read more about CSS selectors,
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath.

```
String xpath = //div[@data-lynx-name='usernameLabel'][text='User ID']/following-sibling::div[1]
```

The above XPath will will find the `div` tag containing text 'User ID' and finds the next `div` which is is the required textbox.

It seems that you can even use the attribute 'data-lynx-name' attribute of the `textbox div` tag directly.

```
String xpath = //div[@data-lynx-name='username']
```

Selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```