# Fetch child elements under selected element using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Find the elements bellow the `ul` element, as per the following sample HTML:

```
<ul _ngcontent-nkg-43="" ngmodelgroup="option">
    <span _ngcontent-nkg-17="" style="cursor: pointer;">Option 1</span>
    <span _ngcontent-nkg-17="" style="cursor: pointer;">Option 2</span>                                                    
    <span _ngcontent-nkg-17="" style="cursor: pointer;">Option 3</span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 var yourParentElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//ul[ngmodelgroup='option']"));
 var children = yourParentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"))
```

This latter call will return all children elements of yourParentElement

Comment: Could you do this via `CssSelector`?

Comment: This is a late response, so this is to all those that are seeking a similar issue. cssSelector in this context can be solved via driver.FindElements(By.cssSelector("ul[ngmodelgroup='option'] > span")). https://stackoverflow.com/a/26306203/4415253

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to fetch the `span` elements you could do:
`driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//ul[ngmodelgroup='option']")).FindElements(By.TagName("span"));`