# How to find an element present in data-hook through selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the HTML code as:

```
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R252N8IFRXV8TW/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B071NZZHF9">Security concern</a>
```

and i have to search the element by data-hook as the class name is common for other attributes also and href and link-text are dynamic as it is changing for the next element as there are multiple elements that i need to fetch.

Can i search it by data-hook. If yes could someone help me with it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)

Comment: @Anshul Srivastava please use the answer below. Let me know your requirements.

Comment: Please add some more html portion of your webpage. So that exact solution can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

CSS:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-hook='review-title']"));
```

Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-hook='review-title']"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, im able to get using xpath. Thanks :)

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava Accept my answer if it helped! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below code if multiple data-hook item you need.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("review-title"));

for(WebElement elem : list){
    System.out.println(elem.getAttribute("data-hook"));
}
```

Comment: I have already tried using the above code, but i still cannot get the output as it is not able to click on the element.

Comment: Please add some more html portion of your webpage. So that exact solution can be found

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared to find the element through `data-hook` attribute you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-hook='review-title']"));
```

Though you mentioned `class name` is common it will be a good practice to keep the `class name` attribute in the `xpath` as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold' and @data-hook='review-title']"));
```

Further, though you mentioned `href` is changing, I will suggest to use the combination of all the three attributes to uniquely identify the element as :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold' and contains(@href,'/gp/customer-reviews/') and @data-hook='review-title']"));
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB i tried using all the above solution but i was not able to click the element. I tried giving wait of 20 seconds by using WebDriverWait, but still no luck.