# Unable to find an element (Selenium, Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to the following element:

```
<span data-dojo-attach-point="lN" role="btn" aria-selected="false" class="xTreeNLbl">Find</span>
```

The following is the Java code:

```
private WebElement search_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-dojo-attach-point='lN' and contains(text(),'Find')"));
search_btn.click();
```

It's unable to find the element. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Xpath=//span[text()='Find'] use this xpath

Comment: My guess is that `data-dojo-attach-point="lN"` is changing on each refresh. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are wrong at the xpath `//div`
as this is `<span>` tag not `<div>` tag
you should write like this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//span[text()='Find']")).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your xpath is almost correct, you just need to correct tag name with Span

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='lN' and contains(text(),'Find')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to try and find the element using one of it's attribute, like its class if it's unique.
Taken from this previous question ([Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)), the formula is:

`element[attribute='attribute-value']`

So if you have,

`<a href="mysite.com"></a>`

You can find it using:

`By.cssSelector("a[href='mysite.com']");`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the follow code:

`//span[@role='btn' and @class='xTreeNLbl']`

If this code does not solve your error, pass me the html dom code of the page and I will help.