# HTML <input> with a data-search-input but no name or ID that I want to use with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium to input text into a text field. This is the HTML of the input box

`<input data-search-input="certification" placeholder="Full Name or Email" type="text">`

The "certification" string is unique to this specific text input element, but I'm not sure how to use the data-search-input part. How can I use this with Selenium as it is not an explicit name or ID tag?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath should work:

```
//*[@data-search-input="certification"]
```

But also look at [Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute) for css option as well.