# Finding element by using data test id in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

This is my HTML tree:

```
<div data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item"><div class="css-1dbjc4n"><div class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item-Look up items-icon"><div class="css-1dbjc4n"><div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item-Look up items">Look up items</div>
```

I am trying to locate the element by `data-testid`

I have used css selector and xpath which looks like the following:

```
@FindBy(css = "div[data-testid='nav-Look up items-item']")
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='nav-Look up items-item']")
```

But it is not able to locate the element.

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector @itronic1990

Comment: looks correct to me `@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='nav-Look up items-item']")`, how did you use this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to re-write your tree here because this is easier for me to understand this way.

```
<div data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item">
    <div class="css-1dbjc4n">
        <div class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item-Look up items-icon">
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n">
                <div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy" data-testid="nav-Look up items-item-Look up items">Look up items</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could always try selecting the className with something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("css-901oao"));
```

or

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("r-1awozwy"));
```

If that doesn't work you could try using a Chrome Extension like [xPath Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph?hl=en)  to try to find the absolute xPath and find it using something like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div"));
```

But as your trying to select a div the className is more likely to work

Comment: Thanks for the answer but since data test id is the only valid concrete name in this tree, I can use only that. Any idea how to use data test id?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute) help? you could try something like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='nav-Look up items-item-Look up items']"));`

Comment: this is what I tried at first, didnt work :( @Royginald

Comment: That's strange, it seems to work for me. Can you add the code where you store the element in a variable and the first action you perform?

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='nav-Look up items-item']")
WebElement lookUpItems;
```

and you can (let's say wanna perform `.click`)

```
lookUpItems.click();
```