# Selenium click and manual click return different current URLs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, getcurrenturl

I've encountered a problem

I searched this on google https://www.google.com/search?q=sen%20do&uule=w+CAIQICIZSG8gQ2hpIE1pbmggQ2l0eSwgVmlldG5hbQ%3D%3D and manual clicked on the first result (this link is attached with ads),
I got the current url https://www.sendo.vn/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=333629566-13485316726&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9eKR_YCh9AIVCz5gCh2ang22EAAYASAAEgI80_D_BwE

Did the same with the above link, used the code below but it only returned https://www.sendo.vn/ (Missing the params)

Here is the code

```
driver.get("${the_above_google_search_url}")

// Find first result element
Web firstResultElement = driver.findElement(By.className("iUh30"))

firstResultElement.click()

String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl()
```

Any solution to get full url path with Selenium like manual click?

Comment: To be more accurate, change the question title to something like: "How handle 302 redirects on selenium with java?" Or "How get the final url after redirect with selenium and java?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered to your web and inspecting the page I saw that there are two redirects **(status 302)** after the click on the first result on google search:

[image: redirects]

And the second redirect has the url that you are looking for in the **header location** because is a redirect (302):

[image]

If you wait, the browser execute the second redirect and the url is loaded:

[image]

## Solution 1

> Wait until the second redirect and then, get the url with the classic methods.

The web is developed on react, that's why is rendered with javascript. This complicate a little bit the selenium automation.

You need to search an element which presence indicate you that web is ready after the second redirect. I found this:

[image]

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="sendo logo"]');
```

Translate this **querySelector** to [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26306203/3957754):

```
By.cssSelector("a[aria-label='sendo logo']");
```

And [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738528/3957754) for it:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label='sendo logo']")));
```

If after this element, you keep getting the same url instead the full url, just try with another html element.

### Solution 2

> Try to get the headers of the page using selenium

Comment: Tried to click by Selenium, wait for full load but didn't see any redirects on F12 @JRichardsz

Comment: Also tried the first solution but it not work

Comment: Try to inspecting on your favorite browser from google result.

Comment: I've tried with other websites (its search result attached ads) and still got the same problem.

Comment: Share us your code using github to check it